# How can I successfuly port W10 files to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, files, windows, dual-boot, file-copy

I just installed Ubuntu (Dual boot with W10) and I can see my W10 partition from inside Ubuntu with all my files. They seem fairly corrupt on the Linux side (Text editors, web browsers, Steam etc)

How can I port these windows files to Ubuntu without breaking anything?

Comment: This is far too broad a question.  Try narrowing it down to a few specific file types (e.g. plain text files are easily converted with the `fromdos` utility...or `vim` can recognise and work with both unix & windows text files and will even save changes in the original format).  Most office documented formats can be read by and/or converted to Open Office formats.

Answer (score 1):

All the files you indicate you want to more are *executables*. You cannot just run these under Linux.

You can try to run these under `wine`, but you'll have more success converting your W10 setup to a VM (VirtualBox or VMware) and run the programs under Ubuntu in such a virtual machine.

On the other hand why bother with W10 stuff if you already have, or otherwise can install, text editors, web browsers and steam directly under Ubuntu.

Comment: Well I don't see a point in re-downloading hundreds of GB's worth of files, and thus I wanted to maybe port my files from windows.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing downloaded data with downloaded programs? You indicated programs, but your download size make it more likely that you are referring to data (videos, music, PDF files). You should be able to use most data without problems directly or after conversion.

Comment: Im reffering to both. I'd ultimately like to ransfer both data and downloaded programs, since my Internet is fairly bad and downloading everything again will be a pain

Comment: @VaggelisD For some steam games that have both windows and linux versions, you could tell Steam Linux to start installing the game, stop it as soon as it has created the game dir & started dl-ing.  then copy the windows version of the game into the linux version's directory.  Then restart the linux download (using steam's Properties->Local Files->"Verify Integrity of Game Cache" option).  For games where the game **data** files are the same in both Linux & Win versions, you will avoid most of the download time, because it will only have to download the executables and linux-specific files.